# Why does the piece of code gets circled (i.e. outlined) in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellisense, visual-studio-2019, outline

Why does the piece of code gets circled (i.e. outlined) in Visual Studio 2019?

[image]

Here is the list of my extensions:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After trying to run the `devenv /safemode` as was suggested in the comments I am getting:

> 'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

[image]

Comment: Did you use any debugger extension? And you can check in the Manage Extension to see whether there is something causing it. Besides, when you hit into the breakpoint, did the circle still happen?

Comment: @GardenCat, yes the circle stays when I pause on the code while debugging.
I am using the PostSharp and the ReSharper.

Comment: Please try to use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your VS and then test your project whether it still persists. If the circle disappear, I think it is the effect of the extensions `PostSharp` or `ReSharper`.

Comment: @GardenCat, I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: use [developer command prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to try again.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, I did not see the code highlight any more after the VS restart. :(

Comment: @NiceWork, I believe that you was right and the highlight was due to the extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the piece of code gets circled (i.e. outlined) in Visual
>   Studio 2019?

This behavior is not reflected by VS debug itself, and thanks to NiceWork's help. **l am afraid this behavior is controlled by third-party extensions and from the picture you provided.**

You can try to use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)(remember to run in Developer Command Prompt) to run your VS to test whether this behavior still persists. **If this does not happen, it proves that this behavior is controlled by extensions**.

If you want to want this behavior to go away, you can disable extensions one by one to locate which extension is.

Hope it could help you.